# Vaadin grid - filtering with lazy loading

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have vaadin grid, and it's great that it has lazy data loading from the box. But for some reasons I have custom filters, which I use via

`CallbackDataProvider<> dataProvider.fetch(Query query)`

Query object has parameters for loading by portions (`offset` and `limit`), so I need to set it dynamically **(?)** and somehow listen grid scrolling event to load next part of data when user scrolls down **(?)**

`Grid.dataComunicator` has field `Range pushRows` but there no public methods to get it. And all i have is grid with lazy loading without filtered data or grid with eager loading with filtered data.

So, is there any way to implement filtering data with lazy loading in vaadin grid element?

Comment: have you looked into  DataProvider's "fromFilteringCallbacks"? It may help you

Comment: yes i have. actually i use `CallbackDataProvider<>` as data provider for grid. But when i fetch filtered data, there is no any association with grid condition (offset and limit for querying data)

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of more help but fetchfromBackEnd does not help you when the scrolling hits bottom? I use an endpoint for data to keep things simple-ish

Comment: nope. if i use `new Query(filter)` constructor, fields `limit` and `offset` stay in their default state 0 and 2147483647. so all data fetched from database. if i set custom values to `limit` and `offset` -- only one query to database executed. and when i scroll down, nothing happens.

Comment: I would check "Interface Grid.FetchItemsCallback<T>", if you have not done so. Otherwise contact them because the issue with limit and offset does not make much sense. I am working with grid currently so I might try this myself

Comment: as i understood `Grid.FetchItemsCallback<T>` doesn't support filters, only sort orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem solved by using `ConfigurableFilterDataProvider<>` as wrapper over `CallbackDataProvider<>`.
so, when i filter table, this wrapper adds filtering conditions to all queries, and data loads lazy as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here using vaadin 22. The answer probably isn't in the same context as the question but given I arrived here I suspect others will.

To create a grid that uses lazy loading and is able to inject a filter into the query use:

```java
class SearchableGrid<E> {

Grid<E> entityGrid = new Grid<>();

private SearchableGrid(DaoDataProvider daoProvider)
    {
        var view = entityGrid.setItems(query ->
            {
                // add the filter to the query
                var q = new Query<E, String>(query.getOffset(), query.getLimit(), query.getSortOrders(), null,
                        getSearchField().getValue());

                return daoProvider.fetchFromBackEnd(q);
            });
        view.setItemCountCallback(query ->
            {
                // add the filter to the query
                var q = new Query<E, String>(query.getOffset(), query.getLimit(), query.getSortOrders(), null,
                        getSearchField().getValue());

                return daoProvider.sizeInBackEnd(q);

            });
    }
```

I've packaged the methods into a BackEndDataProvider as the same class
can be used to as a provider for comboboxes.

```java
public class DaoDataProvider<E extends CrudEntity>
        extends AbstractBackEndDataProvider<E, String>
{
    JpaBaseDao<E> dao;
    GetFilterBuilder<E> getFilterBuilder;

    public DaoDataProvider(JpaBaseDao<E> daoProvider, GetFilterBuilder<E> getFilterBuilder)
    {
        this.dao = daoProvider;
        this.getFilterBuilder = getFilterBuilder;
    }

    

    @Override
    public int sizeInBackEnd(Query<E, String> query)
    {
            var q = getFilterBuilder.builderFilter(query);
            return (int) q.count().intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<E> fetchFromBackEnd(Query<E, String> query)
    {

            var q = getFilterBuilder.builderFilter(query);
            q.startPosition(query.getOffset()).limit(query.getLimit());
            return q.getResultList().stream();
    }
}
```

The filterBuilder is where you construct your query for your back end data provider.