# Vaadin Grid - Multiple filters with Lazy loading

Tags: filter, grid, vaadin, loading, lazy-evaluation

We have implemented lazy Grid loading based on the [Vaadin Blog](https://vaadin.com/blog/lazy-loading-with-vaadin-8) article and want to add filters for certain Grid columns. In this case, we do lazy loading by setting a lambda function as a CallbackDataProvider. Please see the code below.

How can we combine CallbackDataProvider with filtering? According to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007350/8791838), the author could solve this problem by using ConfigurableFilterDataProvider as a wrapper over CallbackDataProvider. Sadly, he did not share further code.
Can you please provide us hints how to achieve that?

Our code is fully based on the Blog article and is as follows:

```
public class Person {
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;
  ... getter and setters ...
}

public class PersonService {
  public List<Person> findAll(int offset, int limit) { ... }
  public int count() { ... }
}
```

Setting the DataProvider:

```
grid.setDataProvider(
  (sortOrders, offset, limit) -> {
    Map<String, Boolean> sortOrder = sortOrders.stream().collect(
       Collectors.toMap(
         sort -> sort.getSorted(),
         sort -> SortDirection.ASCENDING.equals(sort.getDirection())
       )
    );
    return service.findAll(offset, limit, sortOrder).stream();
  },
  () -> service.count()
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example using grid of type `Map<String, Object>`. Skipped `getCount()` implementation.

```
public ConfigurableFilterDataProvider<Map<String, Object>, Void, MyFilter> getFilteredDataProvider(String table)
    {
        DataProvider<Map<String, Object>, MyFilter> dataProvider = DataProvider.fromFilteringCallbacks( query -> {
            List<Map<String, Object>> list = fetchFilteredItems(table, query.getOffset(), query.getLimit(), query.getFilter());
            return list.stream();
        }, query -> getCount(table, query.getFilter()) );


        return dataProvider.withConfigurableFilter();
    }


private List<Map<String, Object>> fetchFilteredItems(String table, int offset, int limit, Optional<MyFilter> filter)
    {
        long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String sql;

        if (filter.isPresent() && !filter.get().getSql(true).isEmpty())
        {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM ( "
                    + "SELECT * FROM("
                        + "SELECT rownum rn, t.* FROM " + table + " t "
                        + filter.get().getSql() + ") "
                    + "WHERE rownum <= " + (limit+offset) + ") "
                + "WHERE rn > " + offset;
        }
        else
        {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM ("
                    + "SELECT rownum rn, t.* FROM " + table + " t"
                    + " WHERE rownum <= " + (limit+offset) + ") WHERE rn > " + offset;
        }

        List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList( sql, new Object[]{});
        return result;
    }
```

Setting data provider and adding filter:

```
ConfigurableFilterDataProvider<Map<String, Object>, Void, MyFilter> dataProvider = getFilteredDataProvider("myTable");
dataProvider.setFilter(myFilter);
grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem with your post in combination with https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-providers.html#lazy-filtering .

Comment: My code is from generic system and I didn't want to simplify it to DAO, so maybe someone will find it more useful :)